# Xerox Phaser 3260 printer not working with Cent OS 7

Tags: centos, usb, cups

I'm using a CentOS 7 based Linux system `(3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64)` with minimum packages installed on it, everything is executed via command line only (GUI not supported). I'm trying to use the [Xerox Phaser 3260 printer](https://www.office.xerox.com/printers/laser-printers/phaser-3260/spec-enus.html) with it via USB(only USB required, Ethernet not required).
On connecting the printer it is getting detected as a USB device as it is shown on executing the `lsusb` command,

```
-bash-4.2# lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 046b:ff10 American Megatrends, Inc. Virtual Keyboard and Mouse
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 046b:ff31 American Megatrends, Inc.
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 046b:ff40 American Megatrends, Inc.
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 046b:ff20 American Megatrends, Inc.
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046b:ff01 American Megatrends, Inc.
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04d8:00de Microchip Technology, Inc.
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 0924:42d8 Xerox
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

However when I'm using the `lpinfo -v` command, the printer is not getting detected:

```
-bash-4.2# lpinfo -v
network https
network http
network lpd
network socket
network ipp
network ipps
```

I've checked CUPS is running on the system:

```
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status cups.service
● cups.service - CUPS Printing Service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/cups.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2019-05-27 08:48:31 EDT; 15h ago
 Main PID: 4892 (cupsd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/cups.service
           └─4892 /usr/sbin/cupsd -f
```

RPMs installed:

CUPS:

```
cups-1.6.3-35.el7.x86_64
cups-libs-1.6.3-35.el7.x86_64
cups-client-1.6.3-35.el7.x86_64
cups-lpd-1.6.3-35.el7.x86_64
```

USB:

```
libusb-0.1.4-3.el7.x86_64
usbutils-007-5.el7.x86_64
libusbx-1.0.21-1.el7.x86_64
```

**Note:** The [Linux drivers for the printer](https://www.support.xerox.com/support/phaser-3260/downloads/enus.html?operatingSystem=linux&fileLanguage=en) from the manufacturer (Xerox)  have also been installed.

Comment: I've also installed rpms of foomatic and usbutils and their dependencies.